# Old project not compiling the same as new project. (Weird behavior/crashes)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

*Edited title to reflect dicussion.*

I have an Android Studio project from a friend that seems to compile and run with very weird behavior (i.e crashes, code being cut or simplified in odd ways). I noticed he is also using an out-dated version of Gradle. This being said, I created my own project and ported the code over and it worked just fine. I'm assuming this is a Gradle issue since it controls how the code is optimized. How do I update Gradle in an existing project?

What I've done:

Changed build.gradle and modified the `classpath com.android.tools.build:grade:x.x.x` to the same version in my new project. No avail.

Changed the gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl to an updated version.

Changed File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version and Android Plugin Version to the new project version.

None of these fixed the weird behavior. If I'm wrong about the Gradle version being the problem here, please let me know.

Regards!

Comment: What is the gradle issue?

Comment: There is no 'Gradle issue'. However, the only difference I know in terms of the project I received and the project I created -- is that it is a new project with more up-to-date version of Gradle. So I am assuming it is a Gradle version problem. The code only compiles different for Android 5.1.1.

Comment: The way used to update gradle and the plugin is correct. I don't think that it depends by gradle.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. There must be a problem with transferring projects between people. Same exact code but works differently on two computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean/rebuild the project. You are probably using a newer version o android studio, i highly recommend downloading an old one to mantain old projects.

Theres a lot of changes on every new Android Studio, folders where files must be placed, gradle configs, and there is no way to "update project structure". You can manually update gradle version, but this will not update your config (build.gradle, settings.gradle) and neither your file folders.

Probably the errors you said are caused by the way gradle build files, its trying to build an old structure following a new structure rule.

Comment: While this topic seems to be steered away from the original question, this is the answer that most helps in this situation. Thank you.

Quick addition though: You are saying that the reason that I am getting the crashes/odd behavior is because the project I have on is a more updated version of Android Studio and Gradle? There is no way to update the project fully without creating a new project? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the configuration files on old and newer versions of gradle/android studio work diferently. Even if you manage to find the configuration which is causing this behavior and manually update it to match the new version you will run into other issues. Yes, theres guarantee way. But just download an old version, you can use the same sdk, i suggest this because probably you will manage other old projects in the future, and you will lose a lot of time trying to figure out how to solve the bugs each of them will give.

Comment: The situation here is that the old project did not work. When transferring it to my computer it also did not work. After creating a fresh project and transferring over, it worked. Perhaps it was a specific version of Gradle that did not like the project? I see what you are saying though.

Comment: Yes, i work with a lot of projects, and i use specific android studio version for each project. Usualy the version 0.9 will do for old projects (7+ months). It works when you create a new project because the problem is not in java or res files, its in gradle build files.